# What is a PPP Adapter?

Tags: ppp

**What is a PPP adapter, I have learned that It helps in connecting LANs to WANs. How does it help in normal pc?**
I have got two interface IPs for my pc when I typed the command ipconfig /all.
One is for Ethernet adapter interface, another is for PPP Adpter.

Comment: @pnuts actually I made the search on google "what is a ppp adapter" and the first answer is this one ...

Answer (score 2):

`PPP` stands for [Point to Point Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-point_protocol). The adapter provides the computer the ability to use the protocol over the existing network interfaces. Originally PPP was used for dial-up access via Plain Old Telephone Systems (POTS), but is now used in conjunction with DSL internet connections and some VPN services to provide a framework for authentication and encryption between two points (usually PPPoE aka PPP over Ethernet).